# Installing pandas with dockerfile for ARM/V7 architecture gets stuck

Tags: pandas, docker, pip, arm

I want to build a Docker Image based on a Python 3.8 Image and then install some requirements including Pandas on a ARM/V7 platform. But when it comes to install the pip requirements the process gets stuck.

Is there any way to use a different base image or change something else in the Docker file to run pandas in a Docker image on a device with ARM/V7 architecture?

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8@sha256:45fbccbc4681e8d9ef517d43f9d0eb8f17b2beac00b0f9697bbf85354ae8a266

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8002/tcp

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "-m", "monitoring"]
```

The requirements.txt:

```
pandas==1.3.3
requests==2.26.0
```

When i am building the Image with `docker build -t rfu .` i get the following output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   25.6kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.8@sha256:45fbccbc4681e8d9ef517d43f9d0eb8f17b2beac00b0f9697bbf85354ae8a266
 ---> 0c665e140292
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in a5e6772c20f9
Removing intermediate container a5e6772c20f9
 ---> 5e7807e6f975
Step 3/7 : EXPOSE 8002/tcp
 ---> Running in d9f6cdc8aca1
Removing intermediate container d9f6cdc8aca1
 ---> bcd057ff5d87
Step 4/7 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> d11ccce85d46
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in cd920fa4c18d
Collecting pandas==1.3.3
  Downloading pandas-1.3.3.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
```

This is where the process get stuck.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it takes time for compiling... Just use precompiled packages from https://piwheels.org/

```
RUN pip install --index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I ended up bumping my python version to 3.9 and using pandas==1.5.3